# C pointer address changes without assignment

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I am working on a Uni assignment here, and I've run into a problem. I am attempting to store a string input at a point inside a struct using a for-loop. Later on I intend to use the pointer to the place where the data was stored to fetch the string. Now the problem is, as I move on inside my for-loop, the address of the point changes as well. This code:

```
printf("B: %p\n", txt->point);
for(i = 0; i < input_sz; i++)
{
    txt->point[i] = input[i];
}
printf("A: %p\n", txt->point);
```

gives the output:

```
B: 0x7fc111803200
A: 0x7fc111803265
```

where B is before-value and A is after-copying value.

Any help debugging this would be very appreciated!

---

EDIT: Here's some more code:

The struct:

```
struct text_storage {
    char* start;
    char* point;
    char* end;
} typedef text_t;
```

Initialization function:

```
text_t* text_init(void *memory, size_t size)
{
    text_t* to_return;
    if(size < sizeof(text_t))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    to_return = (text_t*) memory;
    to_return->start = to_return;

    to_return->end = to_return->start + size;
    to_return->point = to_return->start;

    printf("Start: %p, point: %p, end: %p, end-start: %d\n", to_return->start, to_return->point, to_return->end, (to_return->end - to_return->start));


    return to_return;
}
```

The text-store method in which the error occurs:

```
int text_store_entry(text_t *txt, const char *input, size_t input_sz)
{
    int to_return;
    char* begin = txt->point;
    int i;

    if(input_sz > (txt->end - txt->point))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Start: %p, point: %p, end: %p, end-start: %d\n", txt->start, txt->point, txt->end, (txt->end - txt->start));


    printf("B: %p\n", txt->point);
    for(i = 0; i < input_sz; i++)
    {
        txt->point[i] = input[i];
    }
    printf("A: %p\n", txt->point);

}
```

Main-function (testing purposes only):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* memory = malloc(10000);
    char* a = "hei pa deg din trekkbasun";
    text_t* txt;
    int memoverwritten;

    txt = text_init(memory, 10000);

    memoverwritten = text_store_entry(txt, a, (size_t)26);


    printf("got through\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show declarations and other code. - probably Undefined behaviour

Comment: Added lots of more code now. Thanks @GrijeshChauhan

Comment: But I can't see where do you call `text_store_entry()` function ?

Comment: That's in the main-function, I'll add it. It's for testing purposes only.

Comment: `to_return->start = to_return;` looks wrong `start` is `char*` pointer and `to_return` is of type `text_t*`.

Comment: `void* memory = malloc(10000);` is wrong its should be `void* memory = malloc(10000 * sizeof text_t);` even then many mistakes. and `10000` is not a good choice.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That seems to be working actually. When I do the first print, it says:    

Start: 0x7fc111803200, point: 0x7fc111803200, end: 0x7fc111805910, end-start: 10000

Comment: Haha, I'm working on this assignment, too! +1 for relevance (to my interests)

Answer (score 3):

The problem most probably is due to the initialization of structures of type `struct text_storage`.  Such structures contain three pointers to text.  Each pointer should be initialized, possibly with a `malloc`.  Your `text_init` function does not do that properly.
In fact, the place where the `start` pointer is stored overlaps with the first bytes of the memory that you want to use.

I'm guessing that you need a structure like this:

```
typedef struct text_storage {
    char* start;
    char* point;
    char* end;
    char* data;
} text_t;
```

initialized with a function like this:

```
text_t text_init(void *memory, size_t size)
{
  text_t to_return;
  to_return.data = (char *) memory;
  to_return.start = to_return.data;
  to_return.end = to_return.start + size;
  to_return.point = to_return.start;
  return to_return;
}
```

Comment: The assignment specifies that the only heap space we are allowed to use is the one passed to the text_init function. We are not allowed to reserve heap memory outside this block. That leaves me with no malloc I'm afraid :(

Comment: OK, no `malloc`, see above.  If you want the `memory` to store the complete structure, you'll need a struct with a last field of variable size, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641698/allocating-struct-with-variable-length-array-member).

Comment: Thank you! So you're using another pointer to data? How do you think about changing the start and end pointers into null-length arrays? Then they will take 0 bytes and only point to somewhere in memory, right?

Comment: You cannot have two zero length arrays in the same structure.  You can have just one such field and it must be **the last** one.  This is a trick, useful if you have structures whose actual length you don't know but only their first fields.  Avoid it, if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to follow your advice here, but I'm getting a compiler error at the line `to_return.end = to_return.start + size;`. Any idea why? I cannot see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: What does the compiler error say?  It compiles OK here.  You have `#include <stdlib.h>`, I suppose (it's needed for `size_t`).

Answer (score 0):

Print txt->point in the loop and see the point at which it changes. I'm guessing it changes when assigning to txt->point[0]. I'm not fully familiar with printf, so I'm not sure what it's printing out for you, but the name of an array references the first location. If printf is printing out a pointer, txt->point[i] is always a char pointer, and printf may be dereferencing txt->point, which will get it the first entry, and then showing the address there, which you do assign when you change the point to input[i].

Comment: That seems to be right. The address of the point changes to the new value (+65 from the start) as it enters the first iteration, and keeps this value throughout the loop. When printing the address of txt->point[i] inside the loop, I can see that it moves 4 bytes for each iteration. Which makes sense because we're storing chars.

Comment: In that case, change your printf statement to print &txt->point[0], and hopefully it will remain constant, showing you that your array is not moving. Though I wouldn't have expected printf to change on every iteration as you say it does, so leaves me wondering.

Comment: Such debugging is not necessary, the problem is clear.  In the way structures are initialized, `txt`, `&(txt->start)` and `txt->start` all point to the same address (`memory`).  When you start adding text, you  erase the value of `txt->start`.